# Pushed route is ignored by client

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up a vpn server to get a virtual LAN with some friends. The vpn will not be used to route traffic to the internet.

The server is configured to hand out IP addresses x.y.z.* with:

```
server x.y.z.0 255.255.255.0
```

and it tells clients to use the vpn to access addresses in the vpn by pushing a route:

```
push "route x.y.z.0 255.255.255.0"
```

We also configure clients to "Use this connection only for resources on its network".

This works as intended from a Debian computer but it does not work from a Ubuntu computer. It cannot ping the server x.y.z.1 and I assume it is caused by the subnet mask being 255.255.255.255. The pushed route seems to be ignored. When trying to change the subnet mask manually from the client side, it cannot even connect to the vpn.

Am I understanding this correctly? Any hints on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Look at the syslog on the other system with openvpn set to at least `verb 3`.  Do you see the route in the PUSH reply?  Does openvpn log errors when attempt to add the rout?

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, I see the push but no errors: PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST' SENT CONTROL [client2]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route x.y.z.0 255.255.255.0,route x.y.z.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig x.y.z.10 x.y.z.9,peer-id 2' (status=1)

Comment: I don't like that `status=1` bit—IMO it indicates the failure. Is the message the same on Debian (where it works)?

Comment: @kostix `status=1` is the same for the working client. But there is a difference in the end of the log message: ...peer-id 1,cipher AES-256-GCM' (status=1). So may be something with the encryption failing?

Comment: What does the route table of the broken host look like? There could be a conflicting route in the table